# how to check if a list of column in not present in a dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a dataframe (df) and list (l) containing a list of column names.
df:

| Col_A | Col_B | Col_D | Col_G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 12 | Q | no |
| BB | 23 | W | yes |
| WW | 44 |  | yes |

```
l = ['Col_A', 'Col_B', 'Col_C', 'Col_D', 'Col_E', 'Col_F', 'Col_G']
```

I would like to print the column names that are not present in the df.

Desired output:

```
['Col_C', 'Col_E', 'Col_F']
```

What I tried so far:

```
if l not in df.columns:
    print(l)
```

I get an error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.setdiff1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html):

```
L = np.setdiff1d(l, df.columns).tolist()
```

Or [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
L = pd.Index(l).difference(df.columns).tolist()
```

Or list comprehension with `not in`:

```
L = [x for x in l if x not in df.columns]
```

---

```
print (L)
['Col_C', 'Col_E', 'Col_F']
```

Comment: Very helpful and versatile answer as I was able to use the numpy.setdiff1d but swap out `df.columns` for a column(pandas series) i.e. `df['Col_A']`

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension for this:

```
[i for i in l if i not in df.columns]
```

This goes through every element in `l` (`i`) and if it is not in the columns of df, it will add it to a new list. Output:

```
['Col_C', 'Col_E', 'Col_F']
```

Comment: EmiOB you took time to write an explanation while other answer write "use:" "or:" only. thanks +1

Comment: @athing - Hmmm, some problem with my person?

Comment: why do you say so

Comment: you were imlplying this answer to delete and i give a reason why not and fastness isnt everything jezreal

Comment: @athing - No, there is no reason for delete. My comment ask for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop over the list `l`.

Like:

```
for item in l:
  if item not in df.columns:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use set difference:

```
list(set(l).difference(df.columns))
```

or

```
list(set(l) - set(df.columns))
```